# Qt environment corrupt Mac os

Tags: qt

I'm working on a project and it's compiling with all of my co-workers but me (we use `Github` to synchronize our work). We all work with `MacOs 10.8.4`. Here's a part of the error I'm facing :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "qt_message_output(QtMsgType, QMessageLogContext const&, QString const&)", referenced from:
      QDebug::~QDebug() in PhTimeCode.o
      QDebug::~QDebug() in PhStripDoc.o
      QDebug::~QDebug() in PhGraphicView.o
      QDebug::~QDebug() in PhGraphicContext.o
      QDebug::~QDebug() in PhGraphicImage.o
      QDebug::~QDebug() in PhGraphicTexturedRect.o
      QDebug::~QDebug() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      ...
  "QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*) in PhTimeCode.o
      QTypedArrayData<char>::deallocate(QArrayData*) in PhDebug.o
      QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*) in PhDebug.o
      QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*) in PhStripDoc.o
      QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*) in PhStripText.o
      QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*) in PhPeople.o
      QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*) in PhGraphicView.o
      ...
  "QArrayData::shared_null", referenced from:
      QArrayData::sharedNull() in PhDebug.o
      QArrayData::sharedNull() in PhStripDoc.o
      QArrayData::sharedNull() in PhStripText.o
      QArrayData::sharedNull() in PhPeople.o
      QArrayData::sharedNull() in PhGraphicText.o
      QArrayData::sharedNull() in PhFont.o
  "QMetaObject::Connection::~Connection()", referenced from:
      PhGraphicView::PhGraphicView(QWidget*) in PhGraphicView.o
      PhGraphicStripView::PhGraphicStripView(QWidget*) in PhGraphicStripView.o
      MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*) in MainWindow.o
  "QMapDataBase::createData()", referenced from:
      QMapData<QString, PhPeople*>::create() in PhStripDoc.o
      QMapData<PhStripCut*, PhGraphicRect*>::create() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMapData<PhStripText*, PhGraphicText*>::create() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMapData<PhPeople*, PhGraphicText*>::create() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMapData<QString, PhPeople*>::create() in PhGraphicStripView.o
  "QMapDataBase::createNode(int, int, QMapNodeBase*, bool)", referenced from:
      QMapData<QString, PhPeople*>::createNode(QString const&, PhPeople* const&, QMapNode<QString, PhPeople*>*, bool) in PhStripDoc.o
      QMapData<PhStripCut*, PhGraphicRect*>::createNode(PhStripCut* const&, PhGraphicRect* const&, QMapNode<PhStripCut*, PhGraphicRect*>*, bool) in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMapData<PhStripText*, PhGraphicText*>::createNode(PhStripText* const&, PhGraphicText* const&, QMapNode<PhStripText*, PhGraphicText*>*, bool) in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMapData<PhPeople*, PhGraphicText*>::createNode(PhPeople* const&, PhGraphicText* const&, QMapNode<PhPeople*, PhGraphicText*>*, bool) in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMapData<QString, PhPeople*>::createNode(QString const&, PhPeople* const&, QMapNode<QString, PhPeople*>*, bool) in PhGraphicStripView.o
  "QMapDataBase::shared_null", referenced from:
      QMap<QString, PhPeople*>::QMap() in PhStripDoc.o
      QMap<PhStripCut*, PhGraphicRect*>::QMap() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMap<PhStripText*, PhGraphicText*>::QMap() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMap<PhPeople*, PhGraphicText*>::QMap() in PhGraphicStripView.o
  "QMapDataBase::recalcMostLeftNode()", referenced from:
      QMap<QString, PhPeople*>::QMap(QMap<QString, PhPeople*> const&) in PhStripDoc.o
      QMap<QString, PhPeople*>::detach_helper() in PhStripDoc.o
      QMap<PhStripCut*, PhGraphicRect*>::detach_helper() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMap<PhStripText*, PhGraphicText*>::detach_helper() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMap<PhPeople*, PhGraphicText*>::detach_helper() in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMap<QString, PhPeople*>::QMap(QMap<QString, PhPeople*> const&) in PhGraphicStripView.o
      QMap<PhStripText*, PhGraphicText*>::QMap(QMap<PhStripText*, PhGraphicText*> const&) in PhGraphicStripView.o
      ...
```

the code compile with everybody expected me, and I've already re-installed Qt via the online installer. I'm lost.

Comment: Why down vote? Be constructive, explain it

Comment: If you have Qt 4.x installed say via MacPorts, you'll run into trouble if you're using cmake as well, but that's limited to compilation, not linking. Otherwise I have no idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you have any **other Qt libraries already installed in your system**(in some other paths). If so uninstall & try.

Comment: The installation of `Qt 5.0.2` was fresh, I've tried, with `Qt 5.1.0` and it says that SDL.h is missing, I'm installing 5.1.1 and I'll see...

Comment: There was a bad flag in my .pro file which was pointing to an old version of Qt libs !